# What tells the router what to call me?

Tags: networking, router, centos-7

My current home server, a machine running Centos7, currently shows up as server_Jellyfin on my home router after installing Jellyfin a couple months ago. It also has a description, "A Jellyfin server."

What is causing this name and description to be set? It isn't the hostname, as that is still what I expected it to be.

Where can I change this? this server is running a lot more than that so the name isn't very apt. I apologize for what honestly seems like a stupid question but I can't seem to find what this is called.

Comment: Did you name the Router?  Most any router has a Host Name filled in by the Manufacturer.  Mine is router8...

Comment: @John I think you misunderstand, the router isn't the thing that has a name. I am in the settings for my router, in my case, the Google WiFi app, and am viewing my connected devices. My server shows up as "server_Jellyfin" even though it's hostname is "server." Meaning that at some point, Jellyfin modified some system file to request that name be given to it, I just don't know where that is, as it isn't hostname.

Comment: I will look around. I have not seen that before. Servers keep their names very well.

Comment: What kind of Server is this (what Server OS)? I have not seen any reason (or experienced any situation) where a user process or router process can change the Server name.

Comment: @John It’s in the question

Comment: Yes. I was not certain. Is this CentOS Server or Workstation?  It may not matter. Something may be installed in it allowing this to happen.

Comment: @John It’s an old desktop computer that i’ve installed Centos on